# selection error in jquery with dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all thanks for reading. I have a problem with jQuery. I am trying to get some data with AJAX and put the result on page with dynamically created div. This works perfect. The problem occurs when I try to select the created div and do something with it

`$('.myNewDiv').css('border', '2px solid #000080');`

It gives me error in jQuery library

In Chrome debugger it is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined" on line 2234

And in Firebug under firefox "Array.prototype is undefined Line 3324"

I have no idea what is the problem so i'd be grateful for any information

The whole function code:

```
function AddNextDiv(number) {
var url2 = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Translate/GetLineDetails") %>';
        $.getJSON(url2, { textLineID: LinesIDs[number], TranslatedSubsID: '<%=     Html.Encode(Model.OutputSubs.SubsID) %>' }, function (result) {
            if (result == "Already in Database") return false;
            var myObject1 = JSON.parse(result);
            $("#MainField").append("<div class=\"TextLineDiv\">This is line number " +  myObject1.LineNumber + " of 423<br/>" + myObject1.TextValue + "<br/><input  id=\"TranslationBox" + myObject1.LineNumber + "\" class=\"translationTextBox\"   type=\"text\" size=\"20\" /><br/><div id=\"CheckBoxDiv" + myObject1.LineNumber + "\"><input name=\"" + myObject1.LineNumber + "\" class=\"addCheckBox\" onchange=\"HideDiv(this)\" type=\"checkbox\" /><br/><div class=\"NumberDiv\" title=\"" + myObject1.LineNumber + "\" onmouseover=\"CallRefresh(this)\" > This line was translated <div id=\"Translated" + myObject1.LineNumber + "\">" + myObject1.TimesTranslated + "</div> times.</div><br/><br/></div></div>");
            $("div#MainField div.TextLineDiv").css('border', '2px solid #000080');
            return true;
        });
    }
```

`

Comment: Are you saying that you don't get the error if you remove the `.css(...)` call? `$("div#MainField div.TextLineDiv").css('border', '2px solid #000080');`

Comment: No, I still get an error with or without the `.css('border', '2px solid #000080')`

Answer (score 1):

You can't select things that aren't added to the document yet.  If you can restructure your code so that the div can be caught into a variable it would be easy.  Otherwise you need to do something like add it to a hidden element then select it. (yuk!)

I suggest using jQuery's DOM tools rather than building everything as a big string of html.

Comment: Far as I can tell, Dominik has added it to the DOM. He's just using a different selector in the single line example near the top.

Comment: Yup, the upper code is just an example. The real jquery call is in the  second code block.